# Passing HTML through Webpack to process images

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, hugo

I have an interesting problem I have yet to solve while working with Webpack.

I'm using Webpack along side Hugo (static site generator) for a handful of projects. Webpack takes care of all transpiling, bundling, minifying etc., and Hugo generates all the content and static HTML pages, including the handling of images. Hugo has to be in charge of the images, as I'll have non-technical people updating them in the future.

I'd really like for Webpack to be aware of the images in my HTML so that it can optimize and generate a responsive `srcset`. I've explored `html-loader` and understand that I can `require("html-loader!./file.html");` to pass HTML manually, to then be passed along to the respective image loaders, but is there a way I can do this dynamically without having to require each of my HTML files?

This would probably be its own Webpack config file to be run post-(normal)build, as Hugo has to compile the site before the actual image sources will be in the HTML. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I am also very interested to hear ideas about this topic!

Comment: I found this package and I am trying to extract the information I am looking for regarding the `html-loader`. Looks like these guys have figured it out. However, I don't want to use the full package since it's not very configurable. I'd rather extract the things I need ;)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hugo-webpack-boilerplate.

Have a look at this file: https://github.com/vseventer/hugo-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: What if you first run `hugo` to generate the HTML and then feed those generated files to Webpack to do its magic? A plugin like the `webpack-shell-plugin` could help define a command to run before the build starts, in this case `hugo`. That's what I am experimenting with at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo is quite capable of [processing images](https://gohugo.io/content-management/image-processing/#readout) natively, and of generating srcsets required for responsive images, using [Markdown Render Hook Templates](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#markdown-render-hooks) or shortcodes. I think render templates are the easiest approach as it means that images added using markdown syntax can be processed, avoiding the use of shortcodes in your content files.

I deploy Hugo sites to Netlify, so also utilize their image optimisations on deploy of the built site, though savings are minimal as Hugo is pretty efficient in that respect.